# Execute a nextflow process for each CSV record (line)

Tags: nextflow

I'm trying to read each line from a CSV file and then execute a Nextflow process for each line of it. However I don't know exactly why when I run the Nextflow script I get the following error:

**Argument of `file` function cannot be null**

```
params.index_fasta = "/home/test_1000Genomes.csv"

Channel
  .fromPath(params.index_fasta)
  .splitCsv(header:true)
  .map { row-> set(row.sampleId, file(row.read1), file(row.read2)) }
  .set { sample_run_ch }

process FastQCFQ {

  tag "QC of fasta"

  publishDir (
    path: "${params.PublishDir}/Reports/${sampleId}/FastQC",
    mode: 'copy',
    overwrite: 'true'
  )
    
  input:
  set sampleId, file("${read1}"), file("${read2}") from sample_run_ch

  output:
  file("*.{html,zip}") into QC_Report

  script:
  """
  fastqc -t 2 -q $read1 $read2
  """
}
    
ch_qc = QC_Report
```

The CSV file consist of a tab file with a header of same names sampleId, read1, read2 where read1 and read2 are the paths of the fasta files. I'm try to change some parameters inside the Nextflow process but without get a correct process.

Comment: Iis your csv file tab separated or comma separated? Your question is ambiguous on this. If your csv file is tab separated your sampleID argument will become the whole line and read 1 and read 2 would be null, which would cause the error you get.

Comment: Yes you are right @Pallie. I'm try to replace tab with comma separate values on file and now i get other error: Unknown method invocation `set`. I don't know if im wrong using set function

Comment: @PercevalVellosilloGonzalez use the `tuple` keyword instead of `set`.

Comment: You are right @Steve. I think this get the process runs correctly. In fact set option is deprecated. Thanks! However i get two warnings corresponding to the two input fasta files that i think the process doesnt works correctly but im not sure: Unable to fetch attribute for file: /home/.nextflow/assets/nf-core/sarek/conf/home/file.fastq.gz - Hash is inferred from Git repository commit Id

Comment: @PercevalVellosilloGonzalez That's an odd error message... Could it be coming from another part of your code somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

> Argument of `file` function cannot be null

As [Pallie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10524064/pallie) notes in the comments above, if the input CSV is not parsed correctly (for example, if the wrong delimiter is used) the variables that you expect to contain strings may actually be `null`. If your CSV is actually tab-separated, use the [splitCsv](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#splitcsv) `sep` parameter to set it:

```
params.samples_tsv = './samples.tsv'
params.publish_dir = './results'


Channel
    .fromPath( params.samples_tsv )
    .splitCsv( header: true, sep: '\t' )
    .map { row -> tuple( row.sampleId, file(row.read1), file(row.read2) ) }
    .set { sample_run_ch }


process FastQC {

    tag { sampleId }

    publishDir (
        path: "${params.publish_dir}/Reports/${sampleId}/FastQC",
        mode: 'copy',
        overwrite: 'true',
    )

    input:
    tuple val(sampleId), path(read1), path(read2) from sample_run_ch

    output:
    path "*.{html,zip}" into QC_Report

    script:
    """
    fastqc -t 2 -q "${read1}" "${read2}"
    """
}
```

Comment: Thanks both Steve and Pallie for the corrections . Yeah in fact the last error is due to a wrong path inside the CSV file